# width doesn't work on li elements

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm working on a menu bar for a site, except for some reason I can't change the width of each menu item. I've tried using min-width's, max-width's, deleting some styles, adding new ones and I can't seem to find the conflicting styles. Any ideas?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/

HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
<div id="header">
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li id="homeLink"><a href="#">home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header-container {
                background-color: rgba(245, 246, 250, 0.29);
                height: 75px !important;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
            }
            div#header {
                max-width: 768px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
                color: #FFF;
                top: 0;
            }
            div#header ul {
                height: 75px;
                list-style-type: none;
                /*li:hover {
                min-height: $menuHeight;
                background-color: #F0F8FF;
              }*/
            }
            div#header ul li {
                text-align: center;
                height: 75px;
                line-height: 75px;
                transition: background-color 1s;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
                display: inline;
                width: 100px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            div#header ul #homeLink {
                min-width: 150px;
            }
```

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have used `display: inline;` for `div#header ul li` and `width` doesn't apply on `inline` elements so make it `display: inline-block;` instead.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/2/)</kbd>

---

Also, you are declaring `id` on your `li` elements, and they should be unique, so defining `id` on each element seems tedious, so if you don't want to add an `id` to each element, and you still want to apply different `width` to each `li` than you can also use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo..

```
div#header ul li:nth-child(1) {
    /* Targets 1st li */
}

div#header ul li:nth-child(2) {
    /* Targets 2nd li */
}
```

and so on... This way you don't have to declare an `id` on each of the `li` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qre6/1/)